# AS2 targeted clip within function not responding

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

.
Hi,

I'm stuck on something that appears simple, but any help would be great.

I have 3 clips on the stage, and my array is set up with their names like so-

```
var enemyArray:Array = new Array();
enemyArray.push("boo1");
enemyArray.push("boo2");
enemyArray.push("boo3");
```

I want to hit these with my "laser" (Dr. Evil voice)

Here, I define "target" with the clip name in my array and it's bracketed number variable "enemy".

```
enemy=0;
target=_root.enemyArray[enemy];

 function updateLaser() :Void
 {      
 trace("target= ");
 trace(target);
```

When executing the function, the above trace returns the correct clip name in the array "boo1".

```
_root.laserBeam.clear();
_root.laserBeam.lineStyle(2, 0xFF0000, 100);
_root.laserBeam.moveTo(startX, startY);
_root.laserBeam.lineTo(target._x, target._y);
}
```

However when drawing the beam, it always goes to 0,0 instead of the targeted clip "target" 's position.

How is that not getting the clip X,Y when the trace is returning the correct clip name?

Also, if I force the clip name directly to test, it works fine.  But this needs to be dynamic of course.

```
_root.laserBeam.lineTo(boo1._x, boo1._y);//<< test only, no use.
```

I've also tried naming the array names with root prefix, but that didn't work.

```
 enemyArray.push("_root.boo1");//test only, no use
```

What the heck am I doing wrong? haha   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ugggh, was right there in front of me.

I was pushing the name in quotes,

```
enemyArray.push("boo1");
```

Though it was correctly returning the -name- of the clip, that means nothing because it was not correctly adding the -path- of the actual clip itself.

Removing the quotes returns the correct level that clip is on, not just it's name.

```
enemyArray.push(boo1);
```

Works great now.